# Fixed Element in Bootstrap Navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

In my navbar I need to have four elements.

```
1. navbar-brand
2. Two items which collapse
3. One item that doesn't collapse
4. One item that collapses
```

Situation on a large screen would look as follows:

```
Brand | Link 1 Link 2 | Fixed Item | Link 3
```

On a small screen it should look like this:

```
Brand | Fixed Item | Button Burger (which includes Link 1,2 and 3)
```

I don't seem to find a solution. I've tried to create two collapsing navbars but this doesn't work and you cannot put a fixed item in a collapsing block. Furthermore, the fixed item (which doesn't collapse) should be right.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Hmm, I'm a little unsure as to the exact layout you're trying to accomplish. Could you please add some images of your desired layout to your question, or perhaps link to a site that has the desired look?

Comment: Please show us on [codepen](https://codepen.io/pen/).

Comment: you can view the navigation here: http://test.digidog.ch/Tests/Issue/inc-content-navbar.html - What you see in large screen is the "Hi" on the right side --> this is the fixed element. When you go small the "Hi" goes into the burger-links. and this is what im trying to prevent. I want the "hi" (which I will  fill later with the username :-)) to stay visible.

Comment: Here is the code pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OOWKJJ